# Excel VBA to move data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that will do quite a lot. I tried to create something based off some other code, but it doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure why. If you could help me... I'm not that good in scripting.

Things this code needs to do:

1. On sheet 2, it should select all cells with data in range B2 and down, to H2 and all the way down, to select all cells that contain data. The sheet does contain a lot of data...
2. Same sheet, the macro should also move this selection down by 1 row. That is, the data from B2:H2 should now be on B3:H3, and the last selected row should be B(n+1):H(n+1)
3. Sheet 1, it should select the cells on a selected row in range Bx:Hx. That is, I click on B4, for example, and it should select B4:H4. I click on C5, it should select B5:H5.
4. Sheet 1, it should cut this selection
5. Sheet 2, it should paste the selection
6. If possible, given that, let's say, the sheet contains data in cells B2:H5, and I selected (and cut) B3:H3, the code should move B4:H5 one row up, to clear up some empty space.

In the code below, Set Sel = Union(...) line gets highlited in Excel VBA editor. I'm not sure why. I think when I tried to erase the "'Will try to move selection down" part, it worked. What could be wrong here? I will try to add more code as I go; for now I just need to figure out why this line doesn't work. Or if you feel like helping me edit it all the way so that it works and completes all these steps... I'd appreciate it a lot.

Thanks to anybody who is willing to help.

P.S. I tried to add the "vba" tag, but it complains that I need to include the program I'm working with. Hello, Excel is already in tags!!

```
Sub Button_Click()
    'Declaring variables
    Dim Rng As Range, Sel As Range
    Dim ws As Sheet2
    Dim OldRow As Long, TargetRow As Long
    
    'Selects range on Sheet 2
    Set Sel = ws.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row)
    For Each Rng In Selection.Areas
        Set Sel = Union(Sel, Intersect(Rng.EntireRow, Range("A:C")))
    Next Rng
    Sel.Select
     
    'Will try to move selection down
    OldRow = 1
    TargetRow = 2
    
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(NumRows).Range("B:H").Cut
    ws.Range("A" & TargetRow + NumRows).Range("B:H").Insert shift:=xlDown
    
    'Copies selected row to Sheet2
    Sel.Copy
    ws.[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: To begin with add `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the module, and compile; you will see that your declaration 'Dim ws as Sheet2' is wrong. And then Numrows: used before initialised, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Based on the code provided in the original post, there is no need to use the `Cut` operation. The intention seems to be `copying values` from sheet1 to sheet.
- Using the `.Value` property to assign values is more efficient than using `PasteValues`.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Const CELL_CNT = 7  ' Col B to H
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    oSht1.Activate
    Set srcRng = oSht1.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B").Resize(1, CELL_CNT)
    With oSht2.Range("B2").Resize(1, CELL_CNT)
        .Insert xlShiftDown
        .Value = srcRng.Value
    End With
    srcRng.Delete xlShiftUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Runtime error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set on srcRng = oSht1.Cells(...) line

Comment: OK, I think it works. I will need to test it a bit more, but so far... No complaints. It does everything I need. And no errors so far. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine, as expected. I gave it a more thorough testing, and it works like magic. How can I thank you for help taller?